# Python 3; pyexiv2 v.2.7 can't load exiv2.dll, although it's there

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyexiv2

Encountering an JPG image which wouldn't load with pyexiv2 v2.6.4, I upgraded to pyexiv2 v2.7, via `pip install`, which went through without complaints.

Now pyexiv2 doesn't load at all anymore, complaining

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Program Files\Python\3.8\lib\site-packages\pyexiv2\lib\exiv2.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The file exists (`os.path.exists("...")==True` just before the `_dlopen()` throwing the exception), and was just installed fresh with the package. I am running "Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Two more bits of information:

- I vaguely remember that when installing the previous pyexiv2 version, the installation compiled something called exiv2. This did not happen during installing pyexiv2 v2.7. Although I do find only the windows subdirectories in the install directory.
- Replacing v2.7 by v2.6.4 again (from a safety copy :-) does not help - now it's broken as well :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Python docs for the ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), I saw a hint that maybe it's a problem with additional libraries required by exiv2.dll.

After installing "Visual Studio 2022 Release Candidate" from [Visual Studio Download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#tools-for-visual-studio-2022-rc-family) (be sure to check the "build tools" checkbox when the installer asks for what to install), all is well again.